# cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

So I'm looking at a code that's supposed to be an example of pass by reference.
This example comes from here:

[image]

When I compile it the error I get here is related to the "int temp=i" line:

> Error 1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'

And the other error relates to the "j = temp" line:

> Error 2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'

I'm guessing it has something to do with pointers. I'm expecting to get flamed for not having a greater knowledge of pointers here as I'm sure it's a simple solution, but please bear in mind that I'm looking at this code precisely for that reason!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swapnum(int *i, int *j) {
  int temp = i;
  i = j;
  j = temp;
}

int main(void) {
  int a = 10;
  int b = 20;
  swapnum(&a, &b);

  printf("A is %d and B is %d\n", a, b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about this `void swapnum ( int *i, int *j){ int temp = *i; *i = *j; *j = temp;}` ? You are trying to assign value of a pointer variable to an `int` variable.

Comment: Looks like IBM (now Blackberry) failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your swap function. Your swap function should be as follows:

```
void swapnum( int *i, int *j ) {
  // Checks pre conditions.
  assert( i != NULL );
  assert( j != NULL );

  // Defines a temporary integer, temp to hold the value of i.
  int const temp = *i;

  // Mutates the value that i points to to be the value that j points to.
  *i = *j;
  // Mutates the value that j points to to be the value of temp.
  *j = temp;
}
```

... this is because `i` and `j` are pointers. Observe that when you call `swapnum` you are passing the address of `i` and the address of `j`, hence pointers are needed to point to those memory addresses. To get the value of a memory address (a pointer) you must dereference it using this fancy `*` syntax, `*i` implies *value of what* `i` *points at*.

Comment: Excellent! Works now :)

Comment: @user27933, then please acknowledge the answer (by accepting it) so that others who have the same issue can easily spot the solution that helped you.